# Canadian provinces not being marked in geochart of react google charts

Tags: reactjs, charts, google-visualization, region

I'm trying to display provinces of Canada through geochart in react google charts. But the provinces doesn't get highlighted even though the abv corresponding to the province is correct. But the values for "population%" gets displayed in the chart( bar in the bottom of the chart)

Below is my code.

```
 <Chart
        width={"100%"}
        height={"100%"}
        chartType="GeoChart"
        data={[
          ["abv", "population%"],
          ["AB", 2],
          ["NS", 3]
        ]}
        mapsApiKey={GOOGLE_API_KEY}
        //rootProps={{ "data-testid": "1" }}
        options={{
          region: "CA",
          resolution: "provinces"
        }}
      />
```

But when i try the same code by providing `"US"` for region and US provinces as data it works perfectly fine!

Is there something that I'm missing here. Can't figure out what I've done wrong.

Thanks

Comment: @WhiteHat thanks for pointing that out. So according to the docs I should specify 'countries' to resolution right ? ```'countries' - Supported for all regions, except for US state regions.``` But that didn't work either. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @WhiteHat yes, all provinces get outlined

Comment: "**that option is working fine**" Working fine in the sense ? ```'provinces'``` can't be specified to resolution if the region is  'CA' right ? i changed the resolution  to ```'countries'``` . checked ! no errors in console ! and it can' be a problem with the api key since region 'US' works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

option --> `resolution: "provinces"` -- causes the provinces to be *outlined*
and should work fine with canada --> `region: "CA"`

in order to *highlight* a province,
prefix the abv with --> `"CA-"` -- as in --> `"CA-AB"`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['geochart'],
  'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["abv", "population%"],
    ["CA-AB", 2],
    ["CA-NS", 3]
  ]);

  var options = {
    region: "CA",
    resolution: "provinces",
    colors: ['blue', 'green']
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="regions_div"></div>
```

Comment: THANKS, you saved me a lot of trouble !!